# Как задать функцию которая будет создавать массив с нечетными числами без итераций

Tags: javascript

```
function generateOdds(len) {
  let odd = 1; 
  let arr = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= len; i++){
     arr.push(odd);
     odd += 2;
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Моя функция работает с loops.

Comment: без циклов - никак

Comment: Что значит без итераций?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Совсем без итераций никак не получится, так или иначе придётся установить N значений в массиве.

Но есть способы скрыть цикл за вызовом одного из нативных методов перебора массива, который можно создать с помощью конструктора `Array(length)`.

---

[Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
function odds(n) {
  let res = new Array(n).fill(0);
  res.forEach((_, i, arr) => arr[i] = 2*i+1);
  return res;
}

console.info(odds(8));
```

---

[Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
function odds(n) {
  return new Array(n).fill(0)
    .map((_, i) => 2*i+1);
}

console.info(odds(8));
```

---

[Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
    function odds(n) {
      return new Array(n).fill(0)
        .reduce((carry, _) => (carry.push(carry.length*2+1), carry), []);
    }

    console.info(odds(8));
```

---

Можно также использовать [генераторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function*):
*Однако, и тут без итераций никуда*

```js
function nOdds(n) {
  var i = 0;
  return function*() {
    while (i < n) {
      yield 2*i+1;
      ++i;
    }
  };
} 

console.log([...nOdds(8)()])
```

Ещё есть возможность любой цикл превратить в рекурсию:

```js
function nOdds(n) {
  if (n == 0) return [];
  let res = nOdds(n-1);
  res.push(2*n - 1);
  return res;
} 
function nOdds2(n) {
  if (n == 0) return [];
  return nOdds2(n-1).concat([2*n - 1]);
} 
// (c) Grundy
function* genNOdds(len){
  if(len==1) return yield 1;
  yield *genNOdds(len-1);
  yield 2*len-1;
}
console.log(nOdds(3));
console.log(nOdds2(3));
console.log([...genNOdds(5)])
```

Comment: Кхм, `Array#map` точно так же итерирует, только тссс!

Comment: @Other, отметил этот момент (По сути переписал ответ)

Comment: @vp_arth, а если я вам скажу, что совсем без итераций (в JS) **можно**?)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, таки итерации внутри _Array.from_ - так что не считается :P

Comment: @Grundy, следите за руками - ни одной **итерации в JS**. Что там используется в реализации движка - не мое дело ;)

Comment: @Grundy, ну и вопрос таки про итерации в JS коде, а не про итерации "под капотом".

Comment: А `[].forEach` по вашему не под капотом? `next` в итераторе - такая же функция, которая вызовется N раз

Comment: Вполне себе под капотом. Я же не говорю, что код в вашем ответе ошибочен ;)

Answer (score 5):

Если использовать возможности ES6, то создать функцию, определяющую последовательность нечетных чисел вполне реально. Для этого нужно использовать [итераторы](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Iteration_protocols#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB_%D0%98%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80), но только напрямую, без синтаксического сахара генераторов. А чтобы сконвертировать полученный итератор в массив, можно использовать [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).

Вот так может выглядеть код:

```
const makeSequence = (len) => {
    const seq = {
        [Symbol.iterator]() {
            return {
                next() {
                    return {
                        value: (1 + 2 * --len),
                        done: (len < 0)
                    };
                }
            };
        }
    };

    return Array.from(seq).reverse();
};

console.log(makeSequence(3));
```

А вот и работающий [пример на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3qrm6Ly5/1/).

Comment: Сконвертировать **итератор** в массив без *итераций*... Ну ок.

Comment: @vp_arth, в **коде** не будет ни одной итерации. Что там делается под капотом в JS - отдельная история ;)

Comment: Мне кажется если избавиться от локального current и просто уменьшать длину length-- пока она не станет равна 0, то будет немного красивее.

Comment: @OlmerDale, не все так просто. `current` - еще и для вычисления значений используется. Но в целом да, код можно сделать красивее. Давайте оставим эту задачу ТС :)

Comment: @vp_arth, более того, вы не может написать JS код, не использующий итерации под капотом в принципе, из-за event loop.

Comment: а почему не сниппет? Зачем фиддл?

Comment: Во-первых `Array.from` до сих пор нет в IE, а во-вторых, jsfiddle удобнее (субъективно) чем снипет.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, IE - умер! Да здравствует EDGE!